# app.set('views', __dirname + '/views') in Express & node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm confused with the app.set() method.
As far as I know, app.set() is like this

```
app.get('title');
// => undefined

app.set('title', 'My Site');
app.get('title');
// => "My Site"
```

but in tutorials, make 'views' folder and use like this.

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.get('/') or app.get('/admin')
```

shouldn't it be like this?

```
app.get(views)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
app.set(name, value)
```

Assigns setting name to value, where name is one of the properties from the [app settings table.](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.settings.table)

**views**

Type:**String or Array**

A directory or an array of directories for the application's views. If an array, the views are looked up in the order they occur in the array.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

This will set your apps view folder to something like:

> /Users/adil/Project/myApp/views

When you actually go to use the view, the `view` name becomes the file path, `minus the root directory` and the file extension. For example, if you had the following file structure:

```
/views/
/views/index.hbs
/views/news/
/views/news/index.hbs
/views/news/article1.hbs
/views/news/article2.hbs
```

You would render the views as follows:

```
res.render('index', {});  
res.render('news/index', {});  
res.render('news/article1', {});  
res.render('news/article2', {});
```

Comment: I've recently dropped using 'path' in my server file. I find it's unnecessary. Any thoughts on this @Adiii?      

Examples:      

* app.set("views", (__dirname + "/views"));       
* app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Answer (score 4):

1. The methods `app.get()` and `app.set()` in express.js are not what we are used to using in OOP. When we use `app.get('key')` or `app.set('key', 'value')` in OOP like java, we just want to set/get a member of a object.
2. In express.js, however, `app.set()` is used to set one of the application settings. see: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set . The  `app.get()` and `app.post()` methods used here refer routes and request received by node.js server. eg: `app.get()` refers to `GET` request and `app.post()` refers to `POST` request

Answer (score 3):

The `views` is a configuration variable that sets folder from which express will grab templates. `app.get('/admin')` also differs from `app.get('variable')`. First is a GET route, that would listen HTTP Server, the second is just environment variable of express.