# Set a Default Path in express.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, web

`app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'))`

What is the meaning of the line above? And what is the purpose of it?

Comment: Maybe this could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961711/app-setviews-dirname-views-in-express-node-js

Comment: @AntonKrug: re your edit, it was a great improvement, but we tend to remove "I appreciate your help" type phrases. Technical writing is encouraged here.

Answer (score 0):

That line of code indicates the main path of your views, for example if you have this hierarchy:

```js
views/index.html
views/home/index.html
views/home/news/index.html
```

would render your views like this:

```js
res.render('/index.html',  /*...*/);  
res.render('home/index.html',  /*...*/);  
res.render('home/news/index.html', /*...*/);
```